# How can you make sense of "equinumerosity" in Hume's Principle in a logicist approach to math, without first having functions defined?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, frege

I'm pretty sure that I am misunderstanding something here, but I'm not sure what.

How can you make sense of "equinumerosity" in Hume's Principle in a logicist approach to math, without first having functions defined?

You want to be able to derive the natural numbers from principles of logic, and so you rely Hume's Principle as a type-lowering abstraction principle:

> The "number" of things with property P is the same as the "number" of things with property Q if and only if the Ps and Qs are equinumerous.

I figure I just don't understand how "equinumerous" is being used here.
Is it required that equinumerosity is witnessed by a bijection, and if so how can "function" be defined without ordered pairs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Frege's Theorem: Equinumerosity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/#3.1): the "bijection" is not defined set-theoretically, and thus there is no need of the *ordered pair* notion.

> **F** and **G** are *equinumerous* just in case there is a relation **R** such that: (1) every object falling under **F** is **R**-related to a unique object falling under **G**, and (2) every object falling under **G** is such that there is a unique object falling under **F** which is **R**-related to it.

In symbols:

> > **F ≈ G = (def) ∃R [∀x(Fx → ∃!y(Gy & Rxy)) & ∀x(Gx → ∃!y(Fy & Ryx)]**

Comment: Cool, thank you very much. That should've been obvious to me since concepts are not defined set-theoretically, and you want to avoid Basic Law V and extensions.

Comment: @user - recall that Frege's Logic was independent from set theory (at that time: the Cantor's version) and amounts to modern High-Order Logic.

Comment: LOL it's tough for me. I'm a recovering mathematician. I hear "course of values" and "extension" and I automagically think set of ordered pairs and set comprehension. It's hard thinking to change.